# browser performance impact of Knockout.js form with thousands of observables

Tags: javascript, performance, data-binding, knockout.js, obs

I'm creating a form where the user will be able to add multiple rows with knockout.js, each row will have a 5 `inputs` and the user could potentially add hundreds of rows.

I want to use [observable array](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) and make it's properties also observable, for each input.

So it would be likely for some users there could be approx 5000 observable properties on the page.

Is there any performance issues which could arise from such an approach?  Could is slow down the browser? And if there is, are there any methods to protect against it.

Comment: "it depends" - on so many things, it really isn't possible to say. If you're concerned, make a quick'n'dirty codepen or similar that writes out hundreds of dummy rows.

Comment: In my experience, the more observables you have bound to a page, the slower the binding process becomes. Here are some tips; http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/03/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-1ifwith.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're using controls with observables en observableArrays that hold 20k+ records clientside and we're now hitting a bit of a javascript/knockout wall. with 5k it still went pretty smooth but it also strongly depends on the client's browser/hardware.

1 major issue while updating all items in an obs. array is that if you'll iterate the change it would hang the page until the end of the iteration. You could use the apply method to get around that if logic allows that. [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

I'd say if you're 100% sure it won't grow over 5k, go for it, it'll work. But honestly  nowadays you'd probably be better of leaving most of the data on the server and only retrieve what you need at that point.

Comment: thanks that's good to know. Interestingly the data is not coming from the server, the client uploads a CSV which they need to be able to edit the values of :)

Comment: I was thinking on your assignment .. if you're looking to create an excel like environment, you'd probably like to know that it's not feasible to have all fields as `<input data-bind="textInput: value" />` actively montoring, it's better to implement something that replaces each "cell/span-value" by an input element onclick/focus so you only have 1 onchange event hooked at each given moment, leaving some memory for the 5k records :)